# I want to share song ,but it shows error

Tags: android

I want to share song from my app. I tried this code

```
//here collections.get(a).getpath() contains pathof file  

Uri uri = Uri.parse(collections.get(a).getpath());
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("audio/mp3");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

I can share the song in whats app, But in Gmail or xender it shows error can not attach empty file and sorry the resource cannot resolve.

I have also tried

```
share.setType("audio/*");
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code

Comment: did u debug your code?

Comment: check the uri ie  collections.get(a).getpath()

Comment: Post your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look below code if it helps you

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///"+collections.get(a).getpath()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

Comment: i haven't used "file:///" and it caused the error thanks to all who helped me

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

```
 File file=new File("Enter audio path"); // get your file path here
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath()); // generate Uri of file

  Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  share.setType("audio/*");
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); // put generated uri here
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File")); // it will show dialog where you need to share audio file with different application
```

Hope these help you.